# No task registered for key error while using headless JS

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native, altbeacon

I am using foreground service for detecting beacons since Android Oreo kills all background services, we decided to go on with foreground service to detect beacons when the app is in foreground/killed/in background.

This works fine on android 7.0 and below but on android 8 it throws an error "No task registered for key "didEnterRegion"

This is my code
Helper.java

```
public static void sendNewBeacons(Context context, Collection<Beacon> beacons) {
    if (beacons != null && beacons.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, MyTaskService.class);
            service.putExtra("eventName", "didEnterRegion");
            service.putExtra("beacon", (Parcelable) beacon);
            context.startService(service);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
        }
    }
}

public static void sendRemovedBeacons(Context context, Collection<Beacon> beacons) {
    if (beacons != null && beacons.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            Intent service = new Intent(context, MyTaskService.class);
            service.putExtra("eventName", "didExitRegion");
            service.putExtra("beacon", (Parcelable) beacon);
            context.startService(service);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
        }
    }
}
```

This is TaskService code

```
public class MyTaskService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
private final String TAG = "TaskService";


@Override
protected @Nullable
HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return null;
}

String event = extras.getString("eventName");
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(event)) {
  return null;
}

WritableMap map = new WritableNativeMap();
if (extras.containsKey("beacon")) {
  map = BeaconHelper.getObject((Beacon) 
extras.getParcelable("beacon"));
}

Log.d(TAG, event);
return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(event, map,5000, true);

}

@Override
public void onHeadlessJsTaskFinish(int taskId) {
super.onHeadlessJsTaskFinish(taskId);
}
```

This is my App.js

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didEnterRegion', () =>
    require('./BeaconEntering.js'));
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didExitRegion', () => 
    require('./BeaconExiting.js'));

const myModuleEvt = new 
    NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.BeaconManager);
const rangeBeacon = myModuleEvt.addListener('didRangeBeacons', 
    Util.didRangeBeacons);

const exitRegion = myModuleEvt.addListener('didExitRegion', 
    Util.didExitRegion);

const entryRegion = 
    myModuleEvt.addListener('didEnterRegion',Util.didEnterRegion);
```

This is a log before crash

09-12 20:03:25.801 15850-22489/com.kr_beaconmanager D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON

09-12 20:03:25.802 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/ScanJob: We are inside a beacon region.  We will not scan between cycles.

09-12 20:03:25.809 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/System.out: null checkBeacons [id1: 341e458b-ad9e-4981-b01f-ddbce8f43d5c id2: 18 id3: 18]
    handleNewAndRemovedBeacon 1 >< 0

09-12 20:03:25.824 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/System.out: showNotification didRangeBeaconsInRegion

09-12 20:03:25.828 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/System.out: didEnterRegion

09-12 20:03:25.830 15850-15913/com.kr_beaconmanager E/ReactNativeJS: No task registered for key didEnterRegion

09-12 20:03:26.031 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/CycledLeScanner: Using Android O scanner

09-12 20:03:26.033 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/ScanJob: Using immediateScanJobId from manifest: 208352939 Running immediate scan job: instance is org.altbeacon.beacon.service.ScanJob@f13f916

09-12 20:03:26.034 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager I/ScanJob: scanJob version 2.15.1 is starting up on the main process

09-12 20:03:26.035 15850-15855/com.kr_beaconmanager I/zygote: Compiler allocated 4MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)

09-12 20:03:26.037 15850-15850/com.kr_beaconmanager W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default Cannot find match for this device.  Using default

[image]

Comment: can you show the details of the error including stack trace?  Or a screenshot of it shows up as a dialog?

Comment: @davidgyoung added both

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with HeadlessJSTaskService, but I suspect there is some problem with this call not working on Android 8 `AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didEnterRegion', () =>
    require('./BeaconEntering.js'));` You probably need help from a more experienced ReactNative developer.  I'd suggest making a simpler example of the problem that does not use beacons (it is hard to find experts on both beacons and ReactNative) and then post a new question specifically about doing this with HeadlessJSTaskService on Android 8.

Comment: Great that helps! Thanks @davidgyoung

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix, 
We need to define the function first

```
const didEnterRegion = async (data) => {
  console.log(data);
};
```

and then register the headlessTask

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('didEnterRegion', () => didEnterRegion);
```